# Scaling AWS AppSync beyond 1000 rps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

AWS throttles AppSync to 1000 rps per API. What can be done if expected request rate is 50000 rps?

Comment: Many of these limits are soft. Ask AWS support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Amazon's [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html), you can't manually increase requests per second on your own. Depending on your account, you may be able to request an increase by selecting "Service limit increase" in the [AWS Support Center](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html).